# Best way to output a UIView to UIImage with additional views "inserted" on it

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm creating an app that allows the user to place "stickers" onto an image. I then want to be able to output the image (at its original resolution) with the additional stickers in place.

I'm storing all the positions and sizes relative to the size of the image so that isn't a problem. The problem is I'm just not sure how best to go about outputting the image.

I ***could*** create a `UIView` with the image in and subViews etc... and then render that view out to a UIImage. But with large images I have a feeling that's going to either be 1) slow or 2) memory hungry.

Is that the only way to do it? I feel like there should be some CIImage composite thing that will do what I want but not sure with having a `UIImage` and `UIViews`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote something similar as a UIImage category a few years ago.....

```
// NOTE! this method should only be called from the main thread because of
// UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
- (UIImage *)merge:(UIImage *)image atRect:(CGRect)pos overlay:(BOOL)overlay fillColor:(UIColor *)fill 
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size);

    UIImage *bottom = (overlay)?self:image;
    UIImage *top = (overlay)?image:self;

    CGRect lf = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);

    CGRect bottomRect = (overlay)?lf:pos;
    CGRect topRect = (overlay)?pos:lf;

    if (fill){
        [fill setFill];
        CGContextFillRect (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), topRect);
    }

    [bottom drawInRect:bottomRect];
    [top drawInRect:topRect];

    UIImage *destImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return destImage;   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way I do it (not specifically sure about the resolution though)
`

```
extension UIView {
    var snapshot: UIImage? {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, 0)
            self.drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return image!
        }

`
```

Hope this addresses your problem